# How to center column content in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the content of every column to be centered, but for some reason all the columns are touching each other.

I tried using `margin: 0 auto;`.

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6 well ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive pull-left img-thumbnail" style="margin:5px 10px 0 0" alt="">
            <h3><a href = "#">Title</a></h3>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Read More</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6 well ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive pull-left img-thumbnail" style="margin:5px 10px 0 0;" alt="">
            <h3><a href = "#">Title</a></h3>    
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Read More</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6 well ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive pull-left img-thumbnail" style="margin:5px 10px 0 0" alt="">
            <h3><a href = "#">Title</a></h3>    
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Read More</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6 well ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive pull-left img-thumbnail" style="margin:5px 10px 0 0;" alt="">
            <h3><a href = "#">Title</a></h3>    
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Read More</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end row-->
</div><!-- end container-->
```

Comment: Tried creating a fiddle for you. Is this how your view looks? http://jsfiddle.net/nH5y5/

Comment: Are you trying to center each image, title and paragraph? Why do you have the images `pull-left`?

Comment: thanks Vimsha, that exactly how it looks like they are touching when in the same  row. Yes Skelly, I am trying to center the content of each column. I have pull-left on the image in order to keep the text on the right side of the image. is there a better way to get that?

Comment: the thing is when i use the well class the columns seem to touch each other. any ideas???